# p5.js rect() detailX and detailY usage?

Tags: parameters, 2d, shapes, p5.js, rect

The official [documentation](https://p5js.org/reference/) on the P5.js website does not include any descriptive usage of the two mentioned parameters - `detailX` and `detailY` (for the `rect()` function under "Shapes 2D primitives").

The only statements written for these two parameters are "Integer: number of segments in the x-direction" and "Integer: number of segments in the y-direction" respectively.

But these do not explain the usage and I tried to use these and see the result but there is no visible difference that can tell them apart. I had a doubt that they have something to do with the corner radius but that's not it. For that, tl, tr, br, bl are used. And, if any of these four is skipped then the previous value is used for the missing value in the parameter list. This must mean that if we provide just two corner-radius parameters then also all four rectangle corners will be rounded accordingly, and that detailX and detailY are not here for this purpose.

So, what is the purpose of these two parameters?

I have tried so many keyword combinations on google search to get an answer but didn't find anything on this. It is possible that I missed something. Please clarify this doubt.

Comment: I have also checked the ellipse() parameter "detail" that again only has one line description of "Integer: number of radial sectors to draw". What is this for? Why is there no explanation to use these parameters when the documentation even explains the simplest details like width and height of the shapes?

Answer (score 0):

The `detailX` and `detailY` parameters are only used in WebGL rendering.

Note that P5.js is open source, and you can view its source [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js). Specifically, the `rect()` function starts [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/src/core/shape/2d_primitives.js) and is implemented for 2D [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/src/core/p5.Renderer2D.js). From what I can tell, nothing in the 2D renderer actually uses the `detailX` or `detailY` parameters.

However, the `rect()` function for the WebGL renderer is [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/src/webgl/3d_primitives.js) and it does use the `detailX` and `detailY()` parameters.

```
p5.RendererGL.prototype.rect = function(args) {
  var perPixelLighting = this.attributes.perPixelLighting;
  var x = args[0];
  var y = args[1];
  var width = args[2];
  var height = args[3];
  var detailX = args[4] || (perPixelLighting ? 1 : 24);
  var detailY = args[5] || (perPixelLighting ? 1 : 16);
  var gId = 'rect|' + detailX + '|' + detailY;
  if (!this.geometryInHash(gId)) {
    var _rect = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i <= this.detailY; i++) {
        var v = i / this.detailY;
        for (var j = 0; j <= this.detailX; j++) {
          var u = j / this.detailX;
          var p = new p5.Vector(u, v, 0);
          this.vertices.push(p);
          this.uvs.push(u, v);
        }
      }
      // using stroke indices to avoid stroke over face(s) of rectangle
      if (detailX > 0 && detailY > 0) {
        this.strokeIndices = [
          [0, detailX],
          [detailX, (detailX + 1) * (detailY + 1) - 1],
          [(detailX + 1) * (detailY + 1) - 1, (detailX + 1) * detailY],
          [(detailX + 1) * detailY, 0]
        ];
      }
    };
    var rectGeom = new p5.Geometry(detailX, detailY, _rect);
    rectGeom
      .computeFaces()
      .computeNormals()
      ._makeTriangleEdges()
      ._edgesToVertices();
    this.createBuffers(gId, rectGeom);
  }
```

The `detailX` and `detailY` parameters are then passed into p5.Geometry, which you can view [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/src/webgl/p5.Geometry.js).

So it looks like WebGL is using these parameters to set the detail level of the shapes it's drawing. My guess is that this is useful for things like textures or shaders.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; however, I don't think it's a typo. I did go through their source code and found that they are specifying some segments in x and y axes directions with these parameters. I also found that "detail" parameter is also used with ellipse() as I stated in my previous comment. Thanks to you linking the code in your reply, I again skimmed it and found that they have mentioned it for other shapes too. And, as stated there, it is an "optional parameter for WebGL mode only".

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about. I think there should be more detail added in their documentation page regarding these parameters.

Comment: @CuriousCS Cool, P5.js is open source. Feel free to make any improvements you think should be added!